# How to handle Json error code returned from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am working with inherited code, communicating with essentially a 3rd-party device. My dev suite is VS 2015, using C# with the NewtonSoft.Json library.

My "top level" routine looks a little like this (some details omitted for clarity):

```
public JsonResponse<T> SendTypedApiRequest<T>(JsonCommand command, 
    string apiPath, string description, int expectedResponseCode = 0)
{
    try
    {
        var r = SendPost(apiPath, command);
        if (r.Code == OK && r.Response != null) {
            var jsonResponse = JsonResponse<T>.Deserialize(r.Response);

            if (jsonResponse.RetCode != expectedResponseCode) {
                // handle errors
             }
         }
    }
    catch(){};
}
```

In another file I have the following:

```
    public static JsonResponse<T> Deserialize(string json, 
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse<T>>(json, settings);
    }
```

My expected return from the device for this post is this, a numeric value, so T in this case is 'int' (or rather JsonResponse of int):

```
{"retCode":0,"retMsg":"OK","data":41272}
```

However, when the proper preconditions are not met I get this instead:

```
{"retCode":1000,"retMsg":"No admin","data":{}}
```

Seems fair enough right? However, since this is a typed response deserializer it chokes on the {}, expecting an integer instead of the opening curly brace. What I get is a JsonReaderException "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {." What I want to get is the retCode and retMsg from the Json response, so I can pass the actual error condition back up to the user. The JsonReaderException is not helpful at all.

I tried using the JsonSerializerSettings for Null and Empty values but they don't work in this case. I can't seem to find a standard way to deal with this case. I could put a try/catch around the final call to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() to pull the actual error from the response and chase it back up the stack, but that seems pretty crude and clumsy -- there is no logic to deal with that until I am 3 or 4 levels up in the code (everything is expecting a typed response).

Is there an elegant way to deal with this? Is there a canonical way to deal with this? It seems every approach I come up with is either clumsy and ugly or doesn't work at all.

TIA, Dave

Comment: What is `JsonResponse`?

Comment: I think you can do two things here. In your model, change `data` to be of a nullable int. Then make sure to deserialize the JSON with the ignore null values setting enabled.

Comment: JsonResponse if a local class - I missed that as I am fairly new to Json and this code has a lot of legs. If necessary I can post the bare bones of the class here as an edit...

Comment: Nevermind, I saw you you need a generic solution. See if the null ignore setting is sufficient. Also, in this specific case, make sure `T` is `int?`.

Comment: The null ignore doesn't ignore the empty class designator {} returned. No effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to create a custom `JsonConverter` for your `JsonResponse<T>` to handle the type disparity.  The idea is to load the JSON data into an intermediate `JObject`, then process the "well-behaved" properties (e.g. `RetCode, RetMsg`) and the possibly incorrect `Data` property in separate steps.  That way if the conversion of the `Data` property fails, you can still recover the rest of the response.

Here's what the converter might look like:

```
public class JsonResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType &&
               objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(JsonResponse<>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Load JSON data into a JObject
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Remove the problematic data property from the JObject
        JProperty dataProp = obj.Property("data");
        if (dataProp != null) dataProp.Remove();

        // Create a JsonResponse object and populate it with the 
        // well-behaved properties in the JObject (e.g. RetCode, RetMsg)
        object jsonResponse = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), jsonResponse);

        try
        {
            // Now try to add the data property into the same response
            if (dataProp != null)
            {
                JObject data = new JObject(dataProp);
                serializer.Populate(data.CreateReader(), jsonResponse);
            }
        }
        catch (JsonException) { }  // if it doesn't work, eat the exception

        return jsonResponse;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, you can add it to the `JsonSerializerSettings` in your `SendTypedApiRequest<T>` method and pass the settings to your `JsonResponse<T>.Deserialize` method.

```
    var r = SendPost(apiPath, command);
    if (r.Code == OK && r.Response != null)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new JsonResponseConverter());

        var jsonResponse = JsonResponse<T>.Deserialize(r.Response, settings);
        ...
    }
```

Here is a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oWYkoU

Comment: Awesome! That's what I was looking for. I have 1 comment and 1 issue though. Comment: the CanWrite() method is redundant and can be eliminated - not a big deal, ReSharper flags it. Issue: I get a Missing Method exception, looking for a default constructor for the target "object" in line 117 of your example in DotNetFiddle. That would be the JsonResponse<T> in this case, but it could be anything. I am stuck using .NET 4 as some of our clients still use XP (yeah, I know, but they're in China and...) - could this be an issue with 4 and not with 4.5?

Comment: Regarding `CanWrite`, that was a goof on my part-- it was supposed to return false, not call the base class.  I've corrected it in the answer and in the fiddle.  I overrode CanWrite because WriteJson is not implemented and the base implementation returns true by default.  If you only deserialize and never serialize JsonResponse (probably the case) then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The missing method exception would occur if your JsonResponse class lacks a default constructor (i.e. one with no parameters).  You didn't show your class definition, so I assumed it had a default constructor.  You'll either need to modify your JsonResponse class to provide a default constructor, or you will need to modify the `Activator.CreateInstance()` call to pass appropriate constructor parameters to create the JsonResponse object.  If you can't get it working, edit your question with the JsonResponse class def and I'll try to update my answer to fix it.

Comment: That did it! I had figured out I needed a default constructor for JsonResponse but hadn't figured out how to do it until just a few minutes ago. I have that working now and all is well with the world! The trick is to initialize the Data property as default(T), otherwise the compiler complains -- a lot! Marked as answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat and change the data `int` type to `dynamic`. A bit of a hack but it might solve your problem.